# Load multiple terminals and activate python virtual environments

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, terminal, python, gnome-terminal

I'm working on something that requires me to run a few terminals, each with their own python virtual environment. This takes some time to open manually, so I would like to automate this setup by having a `.sh` file to handle it, and then leave them open ready for me to work with. I'm using Linux Mint 20.2.

For some reason I can't figure out how to write this script. I have tried various things including this:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'cd ~/projects/proj/d1; exec bash'
source $(pwd)/venv/bin/activate
exec bash

gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'cd ~/projects/proj/d2; exec bash'
source $(pwd)/venv/bin/activate
exec bash

gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'cd ~/projects/proj/d3; exec bash'
source $(pwd)/venv/bin/activate
exec bash
```

(I am quite new to linux)

**Edit**: I've also tried `gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'cd ~/projects/qcaas/qcaas_cloud; source $(pwd)/venv/bin/activate; exec bash'`, which just gives `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found`.

Comment: Every line after `gnome-terminal` is not passed to `gnome-terminal`, they are running in the shell you are using to execute the script

Comment: Good to know, didn't realise the significance. I made an edit to the post

Comment: `source` is `bash`, the `sh` equivalent would be `.`

Comment: Ok, `.` was one of the other things I had tried. Confirmed that replacing `source` with `.` also doesn't work, it appears to not do anything, just leaves the terminal open (no errors).